# calculate N percentage of a column value by top n percentages of rows

Tags: postgresql, sql-order-by, percentage

I have a two columns. one the user_ids and another one is production value per each user.
I want to know the percentage of production of top 10 percent of most active users.

I tried with Lead over, but since I do not know how it works, I could not get the right result.

here is a sample of my table

```
userid       | production
42539973@N00 | 6572
13407304@N05 | 6765
50780708@N02 | 6958
92607898@N00 | 7826
52996072@N04 | 7889
57868312@N00 | 8226
90484572@N00 | 8444
26650236@N07 | 8802
26650236@N08 | 88802
26650236@N09 | 98802
```

For example 10 percent of users is 1 and if we order them based on the "production" value is the last user and this users produced almost 39 percent of the whole production which is calculated by the sum of production of the 10 percent od users divided by the sum of all the production value.

Comment: How is "most active users" defined?

Comment: based on production value

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add the expected output based on your sample data

Comment: your explanation isnt well explained. please add the expected result and seperate those equations in your explanation to be more clear. Thankyou

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you have not shown us expected output, I've just created SQL for filtering 10% of most productive users with sum of their production divided by production of all users.

```
 with cnt as (select round(count(1)*0.1) no_users, sum(production) production_sum from your_table),
      users as (select userid, distance production, 
                     sum(production) over (order by production desc rows between unbounded preceding and 0 FOLLOWING) production_10,
                     row_number() over (order by production desc) rnk,
                     no_users,
                     production_sum
                from your_table, cnt)


 select no_users, 
        production_10, 
        production_sum, 
        round(production_10/production_sum*100,2) prc_production  
   from users 
  where no_users=rnk
```